# Python pandas Datetime unspecified YMD:hm to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe containing tidal data. The data in the datetime column is unedited as from the xml file, ~ [src](https://getij.rws.nl/data2022/xml/hwlw-WESTTSLG-20220101-20221231.xml), and is structured as `202201010113`.  I would like to change the first column to a "real" datetime >>> 2022-01-01 01:13 or %Y %M %D %h %m as per [strftime format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

The dataframe tide:
`tide = pd.read_xml(xml)`
`print(tide.head())`

```
       datetime tide  val
0  202201010113   LW  -88
1  202201010731   HW   97
2  202201011348   LW  -89
3  202201012001   HW   90
4  202201020220   LW  -96
```

using pd.to_datetime resolved in the following:

```
pd.to_datetime(tide.datetime)
0      1970-01-01 00:03:22.201010113
1      1970-01-01 00:03:22.201010731
2      1970-01-01 00:03:22.201011348
3      1970-01-01 00:03:22.201012001
4      1970-01-01 00:03:22.201020220
```

That looks to me as the unix-epoch startpoint. With parts of the  the current year intertwined. Other methods like datetime.strftime and strptime resulted also in errors. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: why don't you specify a (correct) format? `pd.to_datetime(tide.datetime, format="%Y%m%d%H%M")`? You linked the docs, it's all there ;-)

Comment: btw. you're not dealing with Unix time here, so I removed that tag. You have integers that are a direct representation of date & time. Unix time would be a relative number, representing units of time since the Unix epoch.